# Create New Object From DataTable using field Mapping

Tags: c#, csv

I have a table where i store data mappings. My model for that looks like so

```
public class MapperTable 
{
    public string EE_First_Name {get; set;}
    public string EE_Last_Name {get; set;}
    public string EE_MI {get; set;}
}
```

The purpose of this table is to store mappings from a csv so that i can then create an object with those fields. 
So that if the first name field in a csv is FirstName* it is matched to my table and then i create a new object with the value from FirstName* and set the field name to EE_First_Name

[image]

Im saving the mappings via Id and when the user selects an Id I use that particular mapping to map the data from the csv.

```
public MapperTableConvertCsvUsingMap(DataTable csv){
    var namesFromColumnCsvMap = DataAccess.ExportCsvMaps.FindByExp(x => x.ConfigId == idINt).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach(DataRow row in Csv.Rows)
    { 
        var csvMapped = new MapperTable {
            EE_First_Name = row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_First_Name__.TrimEnd()].ToString(), 
            EE_Last_Name__ = row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_Last_Name__.TrimEnd()].ToString(),
            EE_MI = row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_MI.TrimEnd()].ToString(),
        };
    }
```

This works if all the columns are mapped correctly only. If they don't match exactly it blows up. What would be a better way to match the column headers from the csv to the column header definitions stored in my table to create a new object?

I have a csv that looks like this

[image]

It needs to look like this

[image]

The column mapping needs to get stored in the database so that the process can be repeated. The incoming csv may be different than the one shown but should be able to be mapped to the final one using the stored values in the database.

Comment: `incoming csv may be different than the one shown but should be able to be mapped`. You are showing the end result, how can we `divine` what the different formats of the CSVs look like? You need to focus on the intake of data, not the result. There is not enough intake information to provide a reasonable answer.

Comment: What im meaning to say is that when a csv enters if there is a mapping in the database that says a column with a name of " __First__Name" maps to "EE FIrst Name *" read the data from the csv and assign to that field in new object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check first that the column exists in the table/csv to be mapped before trying to access it. You can then access the column if it exists or return some default value like empty string `""` or something else.

```
public MapperTable[] ConvertCsvUsingMap(DataTable csv) {
    var namesFromColumnCsvMap = DataAccess.ExportCsvMaps.FindByExp(x => x.ConfigId == idINt).FirstOrDefault();

    foreach (DataRow row in csv.Rows) {
        var csvMapped = new MapperTable {
            EE_First_Name = namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_First_Name != null && csv.Columns.Contains(namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_First_Name.TrimEnd()) ? row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_First_Name.TrimEnd()].ToString() : "",
            EE_Last_Name = namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_Last_Name != null csv.Columns.Contains(namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_Last_Name.TrimEnd()) ? row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_Last_Name.TrimEnd()].ToString() : "",
            EE_MI = namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_MI != null && csv.Columns.Contains(namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_MI.TrimEnd()) ? row[namesFromColumnCsvMap.EE_MI.TrimEnd()].ToString() : "",
        };

        //...
    }
}
```

The code above checks first that the mapped column name exists in the table to be mapped before trying to get the value in the row. If it does not find a match it sets the mapped object property to an empty string.